# What's wrong with my questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

Six of my recent questions have been downvoted, but none of the downvotes have been explained.  Could anyone explain what's wrong with them?

[image: downvotes]
<sup>screenshot of downvotes reputation change</sup>

These recent questions of mine are currently all scored at -1:

- [Do I need an "Antrag auf Zulassung zu einem Integrationskurs" to do an Einstufungstest or the Deutsch-Test für Zuwanderer?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/14826/6)
- [How can I get a Steuer-Identifikationsnummer (tax ID no.) a month before my date of employment, without physically moving a month before?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/14898/6)
- [Can I start the Krankenkasse application process before moving to Germany?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/14906/6)*
- [What is a “Nachweis über die getrennte Namensführung”?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/14875/6)*
- [Is there a way to search for language courses by CEFR level?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/15068/6)
- [Will failure to deregister from Germany cause problems registering 11 years later?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/15030/6)
- [Is “Wohnen auf Zeit” easier to organise from abroad than normal rental, or do landlords still insist on Schufa, work contract, and meeting the tenant?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/14992/6)

The two questions marked with * are slated for deletion within the next days ([*The system will automatically delete negatively-scored, unlocked, and unanswered questions that are older than 30 days*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/172266)), so will soon only be visible for users with access to moderator tools (requiring 2k reputation, thus not currently including myself).

Some advice on how to improve would be helpful, because my questions are apparently not well-received in this community.

In the past my questions weren't so poorly received, and I'm not sure what's changed.

Comment: Seeing that the downvotes were all done on your 0-scored questions, I'm a bit suspicious about that... Try flagging one of your post and request politely to investigate if this is consider as serial-voting or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System has picked up something from a user who is serially targetting.  We're sending a warning now.  Can't tell you "why" they're doing it, but can at least send them a message about it.  Hopefully it should ease up.