# I would like to answer my own, Community♦ user-deleted question on German health insurance

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

On 23 October, I asked:

[*Can I start the Krankenkasse application process before moving to Germany?*](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/14906/6) (currently deleted, moderator tools needed to view)

On 21 November, it received a downvote, reaching score -1.  On 24 November, it was deleted by the Community♦ user.

Since then, I have discovered the answer to the question.  Despite the downvote and deletion, I believe this question and my answer could be useful to future users.  I have voted to undelete the question.  If two more users do the same, I can answer my own question (which will prevent automatic redeletion if I'm quick enough).  I hope some users may agree that the question can have value for other users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question was deleted automatically as it had a downvote, and being in negative points without an answer was auto-purged by a bot. Since the question is on topic and looks useful, and the downvote might have been [errorneous](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364/whats-wrong-with-my-questions), I undeleted the post.

To avoid this problem in the future we need to vote more: [We aren't voting enough](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361/we-arent-voting-enough?cb=1) so that the points on a question reflects the community consensus more - otherwise downvotes can quickly make questions deleted by the bot